# Need help converting a number into IEEE floating point format

Tags: binary

I need to convert the number $74 \frac{5}{14}$ into IEEE floating point format. Can someone help me with this

Comment: Please stop defacing your questions.

Comment: @SilentMan You know what? You cannot win, even if you continue to deface them your questions WILL remain, MSE has mechanisms designed to deal with what you are doing. Sorry...

Comment: What is the purpose of having a rollback war here? Just notify the mods.

Answer (score 4):

$74_\text{ten}=1001010_\text{two}$

To convert a number between $0$ and $1$ to binary, write a binary point '.'

1. multiply by two
2. copy the integer part to the binary representation
3. retain the fractional part
4. go to 1.

For $\frac{5}{14}$ we get $.01011011011011011011$. Thus, the binary for $74\frac{5}{14}$ is
$$
1001010.01011011011011011=1.00101001011011011011011\times2^6
$$

---

The floating point representation is a sign bit (0 = positive, 1 = negative), the exponent of 2 plus 127 (8 bits), the mantissa without the leading '1' (23 bits):
$$
\overbrace{0}^\text{sign bit}\overbrace{10000101}^\text{exponent}\ \overbrace{00101001011011011011011}^\text{mantissa}
$$
If we wish to convert to hexadecimal, we have
$$
0\text{x}4294\text{B}6\text{DB}
$$

---

The double precision representation is a sign bit (0 = positive, 1 = negative), the exponent of 2 plus 1023 (11 bits), the mantissa without the leading '1' (52 bits):
$$
\overbrace{0}^\text{sign bit} \overbrace{10000000101}^\text{exponent}\ \overbrace{0010 1001 0110 1101 1011 0110 1101 1011 0110 1101 1011 0110 1101}^\text{mantissa}
$$
If we wish to convert to hexadecimal, we have
$$
0\text{x}405296\text{DB}6\text{DB}6\text{DB}6\text{D}
$$

Comment: Also [this explanation](http://colindcarroll.com/2012/02/21/floating-point-continued/), which focuses on double precision.

Comment: @5pm: thanks, I have added double precision to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[This tool](http://www.binaryconvert.com/convert_float.html) does the job nicely, with single or double precision as desired.

[image: Conversion]

Comment: The original poster may have wanted mathematical help converting the number into an IEEE floating point number.

Comment: @Paradoxial That's possible, but does not follow from the question as stated.

Comment: nice link! (+1)

Comment: @5pm: You're right. Nice picture, by the way. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

[Another tool](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/Decimal.html) that I use all the time.